# Java library which has Factory

Tags: java, hashmap, factory

I looking , among the *java libraries* ,  for a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) implementation which use *hashMap* at the section that decides which **object** to **retrun** (instead of *swichcase*)  , somthing like the follow idea  -

```
public class RobotFactory {

 private interface RobotFac{
  public Robot create();
 }

 private class RV1Fac implements RobotFac{
  public Robot create(){ return new RV1();}
 }

 private class RV2Fac implements RobotFac{
  public Robot create(){ return new RV2();}
 }

 private class AiboFac implements RobotFac{
  public Robot create(){ return new Aibo();}
 }

private hashMap<String,RobotFac> robotFactory ; 
public RobotFactory(){
  robotFactory=new HashMap<String,RobotFac> ();
  robotFactory.put("RV1", new RV1Fac());
  robotFactory.put("RV2", new RV2Fac());
  robotFactory.put("Aibo", new AiboFac());
 }
 public Robot createRobot(String type){
  return robotFactory.get(type).create();
 }
}
```

Is there any exist pattern for that among the java libraries (jre7)  ?

Comment: Probably, is there a point to this question?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to provide several implementations out of the box, I'd go with interface+enum combo, which allows easy selection by the user while providing freedom of providing their own implementations:

RobotFactory.java

```
public interface RobotFactory {
    public Robot create();
}
```

Robots.java

```
public enum Robots implements RobotFactory {
Aibo {
    public Robot create() {
        return new Aibo();
    }
},
RV1 {
    public Robot create() {
        return new RV1();
    }
},
RV2 {
    public Robot create() {
        return new RV2();
    }       
};
public Robot create() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}
```

Now a person can simply say: `Robots.Aibo.create();`

Or if you need to determine type from a string you can do:

`Robots.valueOf(type).create()`

Another way to use an enum (maybe more in line with your wishes) is as such:

RobotFactories.java

```
public enum RobotFactories implements RobotFactory {
    Aibo(Aibo.class),
    RV1(RV1.class),
    RV2(RV2.class);
    private Class<? extends Robot> robotClass;
    private RobotFactories(Class<? extends Robot> robotClass) {
        this.robotClass = robotClass;
    }
    public Robot create() {
        return robotClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply say `RobotFactories.valueOf(type).create();`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any exist pattern for that among the java libraries (jre7) ?

If you *really* mean pattern, then the question is kind of nonsensical because Java (per se) doesn't have patterns.  Patterns are things that programmers use when they write their code ...

If you mean an existing class / API that will do this, think that the answer is no.  At least not is the standard Java libraries.

It is possible that this might be supported a 3rd party library, but I suspect not ... because:

- There is not a great "value-add" in implementing this, given that it is easy to implement yourself.
- A truly general purpose implementation could be rather tricky to implement and use.  (I'm thinking of the problem of creating an instance of a generic type parameter ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ClassLoader.loadClass` does something similar but the actual code is native.

Comment: The classloader API loads classes.  It doesn't create instances.

Comment: It creates instances of Class objects, something like `Class.forName(class_name)`. Have a look at the source.

Comment: I know that.  But it doesn't create instances of the classes ... which is what the OP wants.